# best way to remove some lines and keep some closed objects in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder, line-art

I'm making a graphic in illustrator CS2 and want to remove some parts of the image.

[image]

How i want the image to be:

[image]

I have currently four layers.

1. Layer 1 have the circle in it
2. Layer 2, layer 3 and layer 4 has the group which contain the inner-pattern

what is the best way to do that with illustrator cs 2?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Select all

Grab the **Shape Builder tool**

Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key

Click the pieces you do not want.

<sub>Oh, wait. I see "CS2" now.. this won't work for CS2. Use Aziz's answer :)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

1) Select all the elements

2) Effect > Pathfinder > Divide

3) Ungroup selection

4) Delete the parts you don't want

Answer (score 0):

1) Use the pen+ to add anchor points to the lines and then delete the unwanted line segments.

2) You can make them all complete outlines and use the pathfinder. You'll have to duplicate some objects as they'll get consumed in the process.

Your design looks like it's made up of segments of the same size circle.  Duplicate that circle a few times, arrange them properly and use pathfinder to subtract from your primary circle to end up with your wanted shapes.